# compare the row elements in th 2D matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, compare

i need to output the numbers of the rows in which the elements are arranged in ascending order. And I can`t understand how to compare elements. I made some code where I compare.

```
Console.WriteLine("Rows, where row elements arranged in ascending order: ");
for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        double currentElement = A[i, j];
        double nextElement = A[i, j + 1];

        if (currentElement < nextElement)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentElement);
        }
        else if(currentElement > nextElement)
        {
            
        }   
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("there are no such rows");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to add offensive language.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double[,] testData = new double[,]
        {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
            { 10, 11, 19, 13 },
            { 14, 15, 16, 17 },
            { 20, 19, 18, 21 }
        };
        
        List<int> ascendingRows = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            bool isAscending = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < testData.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                double currentElement = testData[i, j];
                double nextElement = testData[i, j + 1];

                if (currentElement > nextElement)
                {
                    isAscending = false;
                    break; // No need to check further, exit the loop
                }
            }
            if (isAscending) {
                ascendingRows.Add(i);
            }
    
        }
        
        if (ascendingRows.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The following rows are in ascending order:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ascendingRows));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows with elements arranged in ascending order.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The following rows are in ascending order:
0, 1, 3
```

You iterate over each row in the outer for loop, then over each element of the row in the inner for loop.

Whenever you look at a new row you assume that it's in ascending order. If you find some element that is larger than the one after it you know that this row is not ascending and set `isAscending` to false. In that case you no longer need to look at the rest of the elements in that row, so you `break` out of the inner loop.

When the inner loop is done you add the row index to your collection of `ascendingRows` (if `isAscending` has not been set to `false`).

In the end you can print out the ascending rows that you collected.

**EDIT:** If you don't want to use `List<int>` you can use an array instead:

```c#
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double[,] testData = new double[,]
        {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
            { 10, 11, 19, 13 },
            { 14, 15, 16, 17 },
            { 20, 19, 18, 21 }
        };

        int[] ascendingRows = new int[testData.GetLength(0)];
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            bool isAscending = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < testData.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                double currentElement = testData[i, j];
                double nextElement = testData[i, j + 1];

                if (currentElement > nextElement)
                {
                    isAscending = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isAscending)
            {
                ascendingRows[count] = i;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref ascendingRows, count); // Resize the array to actual count of ascending rows
            Console.WriteLine("The following rows are in ascending order:");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", ascendingRows));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows with elements arranged in ascending order.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i rewrite this code without using List?

Comment: @EvgenPetrun I added code that uses an array instead of List